# Matlab textscan and date

Tags: matlab, date

I am a newbie in matlab and i will appreciate your help.

```
1,2011-01-01,1,0,1,0,6,0,2,0.344167,0.363625,0.805833,0.160446,331,654,985
```

This is the first raw of my dataset. 16 numeric columns except the second which is in a date format different from that in matlab documentation.

How can I include this in textscan and have 16 different columns?

Comment: What did you try? And what version of MATLAAB? In newer versions, [`textscan` allows you to specify a date format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#input_argument_formatspec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html).

Use:

```
A=importdata('<Filename>','<delimiter>');
```

In this case `<Filename>` is name of the file with abbreviation (`Foo.txt`), `<delimiter>` is comma `','`.

`A` will be structure with `A.data` containg numeric values only, `A.textdata` all elements as strings. If you want to process it, use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).